# JavaScript stops loop execution after push to array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a problem with simple script. I have a model called 'FeatureFlag' which is a tree structure with reference to parent and children. I have also object called TreeBuilder which makes a tree from a list of FeatureFlag elements.

Here is my model:

```
export class FeatureFlag {
    private _id: number;
    private _parent: FeatureFlag;
    private _children: FeatureFlag[] = [];

    set id(id:number) {
        this._id = id
    }

    set parent(parent:FeatureFlag) {
        this._parent = parent
    }

    get parent() : FeatureFlag {
        return this._parent
    } 

    set children(children:FeatureFlag[]) {
        this._children = children
    }

    get children() : FeatureFlag[] {
        return this._children
    }                       
}
```

and problematic method build() in TreeBuilder:

```
public build() {
    for(let element of this.data) { //this.data is an array of dict [{node,parent}]
        let found = this.findNode(element.parent) //searches in tree for node with id 'element.parent'

        if(found) { //if parent node has been found          
             //found.children.push(element.node) //add current node to its children
             console.log(found) //print found
         }           
    }
}
```

When line:

```
found.children.push(element.node)
```

is commented, console prints all found parents. It is ok. But when line is uncommented, console.log prints only once - a first found parent. Why is that happening?

Regards

Comment: No errors in your console?

Comment: @Amy No errors :(

Comment: _"Here is my model"_ why do you call it a model? I'm just curious.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Angular 2 notation

Comment: Notation? Are you talking about ngModel?

Comment: No, no. I put this class in folder models. I will better explain, but I need to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Wierd! I would put a debugger statement before the push and then step through it to make sure it is not throwing an error that is silently getting caught. Also make sure that children.push does not have any unintended side affects.

I suspect that children.push is somehow throwing, perhaps because children is not defined, but Angular is swallowing the error. Also, is findNode for sure returning a FeatureFlag and not something else?

Comment: Is it possible that I switched off printing errors accidently? I wrote a line which should print an error but it does not

Comment: Make sure your web console isn't filtered. On Chrome make sure all the options are selected. I would put a try...catch around it and then `debugger; console.error(err);` Dev tools needs to be open for the debugger statement to work.

Comment: This is not so much an answer as a "debug your code" statement, which would probably be better as a comment.

Comment: This is true, though I arrived at this answer after thinking about it for 15 minutes, so I figured it was the best shot I was going to be able to give it without several hours of research :)

Comment: Added a few more thoughts to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar issue:

```
  var errors;
    let imput_email = $('#loginEmail').val().toUpperCase();
    if (!validateEmail(imput_email)){
        $( "#loginEmail + .invalid-feedback" ).addClass( "d-block" );
        console.log("I can see this in console");
        errors.push("Kiwi");
        console.log("NOTHING IN CONSOLE");
        alert("ALERT NOT WORKING EITHER");
    }
    if (!validatePass(imput_pass)){ // this part was working before push
```

What worked here is just initializing the errors variable:

```
  var errors= [];
```

I can understand that if the array is empty and it has no information that it is an array it is one of those "silent errors". Hope it helps someone despite the 4 years delay