# JavaScript stopped printing errors on console on any browser

Tags: javascript

In some way I switched off error printing on all browsers. I do not know how because in any browser and any developer tools I have the same issue.

For example, this code should cause an error:

```
    console.log('foo')
    let foo = undefined 
    foo.push('sad')
    console.log('boo')
```

Console prints 'foo' but does not print an error. How is that possible?

Regards

Comment: I don't know what you mean. I get a lovely error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

Comment: Are you sure you haven't enabled filters? Can you specify browsers and versions?

Comment: @canon well, once the error is thrown, the program stops. It won't go beyond it, and the other lines won't run.

Comment: Did you add an error event listener somewhere (`window.onerror` or `window.addEventListener("error, ...)`)?

Comment: @canon - fair point. OP please add more information to the question. What browser you're using, what filters you have disabled, etc.

Comment: _"any browser and any developer tools"_ are you sure about this?

Comment: Did you add the event listener or did you not????

Comment: Perhaps a screenshot or two of this happening would prove that it _is_ happening. Without knowing what you did beforehand we're just left guessing.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir,  did not add any event listener. I am using Angular 2. It it related with problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44827435/javascript-stops-loop-execution-after-push-to-array/44828374?noredirect=1#comment76637839_44828374

Comment: Also I do not have any filter, I switch between info, errors, verbose etc but it does not help. Did I broke JS engine? :D